# Why is queue visibility timeout is recommended to be six times function timeout plus batch window?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig

> Set your queue visibility timeout to 6 times your function timeout, plus the value of `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds`

Why can't the queue visibility timeout be equal to the function timeout? Let's say the function has a timeout of 30 seconds, so is the queue visibility. The function picks up the message and 30s passed, the message has not been deleted, now it's visible for other functions/consumers. Then why does it have to be 6 times? And what role does maxium batching window plays in queue visiblity timeout?

Answer (score 8):

> Then why does it have to be 6 times?

The explanation is given in the next sentence:

> The **extra time** allows for Lambda to **retry** if your function execution is throttled while your function is processing a previous batch.

This is just a recommendation. You don't have to follow.

Comment: I know it's for the extra time. Why does the extra time have to be that much?

Comment: I know I don't have to follow it right? Just wondering the reason behind their recommendations.

Comment: @psyud I don't there is any math formula for that. Its something AWS considers as a "rule of thump". In SQS batch  you can get 10 messages at once, which usually are processed in a loop in lambda. If one msg takes 10 seconds to process, the last one will have to wait 100 seconds. Add to this some retry time when lambda fails and you may end up with much greater visibility time then lambda execution time.

Comment: We are adding in retry time in case your lambda fails to execute, not the lambda execution fails itself to be clear.  If your lambda is throttled, this extra time will allow the native retry of the lambda to happen. If your lambda fails, the message will just go back to the queue and wont retry until the visibility timeout has expired. I think the only reason they say 6 times is because of throttling. It doesn't matter how long one messages takes to process, it matters how long the duration of your lambda is.